# Trigger a PeriodicWorkRequest from code

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I'm using a WorkManager -> PeriodicWorkRequest to setup periodic background sync of database with the server.

```
val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance()

val syncFileWork = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<FileSyncWorker>(
        intervalInMins,
        TimeUnit.MINUTES,
        PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_FLEX_MILLIS,
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
)
        .setInputData(mapOf(KEY_FROM_PERIODIC_SYNC to true).toWorkData())
        .addTag("PeriodicSyncRequest")
        .build()

workManager
        ?.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("PeriodicSyncRequest", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, syncFileWork)
```

This bit works fine.

I separately use a `OneTimeWorkRequest` to sync with the server when the user does a, say, pull-to-refresh:

```
    val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance()

    val syncFileWork = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<FileSyncWorker>()
            .addTag("SyncRequest")
            .build()

    workManager
            ?.beginUniqueWork("ManualSync", ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, syncFileWork)
            ?.enqueue()
```

This works fine too.

Now I want to use the periodic request in place of the one time request as well. My main reason is to not double-sync when a periodic request triggers right after a user manually syncs.

Is there a way of triggering the `PeriodicWorkRequest` from code, so I can replace the `OneTimeWorkRequest` with a call to `PeriodicWorkRequest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recall that being an option, sorry.

Instead, keep track of the last sync, and have your `PeriodicWorkRequest` skip its sync if the most-recent sync is too recent.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I'm doing at the moment. I save the timestamp on a successful sync, and skip the periodic sync if it happens within a few mins of the timestamp. It works, but just doesn't feel right. There ought to be a better way.

Comment: @AdiB: It is possible that they might extend the "unique work" system to cover both one-off and periodic requests. You'd name your periodic work "sync" (or whatever), and when the user requested a manual sync, you'd name your one-off work "sync". That would trigger a recalculation of when the periodic work should next be performed. However, AFAICT, all the "unique work" stuff is tied to `OneOffWorkRequest` at the moment.